# Converting feature set inputs into feature class or feature layer for Python Script tool

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, feature-class, feature-layer, feature-set

I want to accept feature set as input and convert it into feature layer or feature class so that I can use the input in select by location in the python script, as the select by location don't accept feature set as input.

For the graphicFeatureSet input I am drawing a polygon and for input_featureSet I am accepting to select featureSet within the drawn graphic layer.
PS: I don't want to use the input type to feature class/layer it should be a feature set.

```
graphicFeatureSet = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
input_featureSet = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(graphicFeatureSet, "lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_featureSet, "input_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation("input_lyr","WITHIN", "lyr")
```

Comment: This demo code shows exactly that http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/featureset.htm

Comment: True, but the feature set type can be random(point, line, polygon) and it will accept multiple inputs. Converting each to a in memory feature class is difficult

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. I also am not familiar with what a graphic feature set is.

If you wish to convert a feature set to an in memory feature class. You can use CopyFeatures_management

```
fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fs,"in_memory/origfs")
```

But I think feature sets can be used in place of a layer in SelectLayerByLocation. They are supposed to be faster.